# conditional module creation terraform

Tags: terraform, hcl, terraform-modules

I have the following main.tf

```
module "vpc" {

 source = "registry.terraform.io/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "~> 3.14.0"
  name = var.environment
  cidr = var.vpc_cidr
  azs             = var.az
  private_subnets = var.private_subnets
  private_subnet_tags = var.private_subnet_tags
  public_subnets  = var.public_subnets

  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support = true
  enable_nat_gateway = true
  single_nat_gateway = true
  one_nat_gateway_per_az = false
}
```

Is there any way to conditionally add this module? Just like when using *resource* which can achieved by:

```
count = var.enabled ? 1 : 0
```

I am asking this because I do not have access to the underling module files, I can only run the module as shown above.

Comment: I'm wondering what prompted the question, since the `count` you show above should work since v0.13 and is the most clear approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beginning in version 0.13 of core Terraform, you can use the `for_each` meta-argument in the module block for conditional management in the same manner as `resource` or `data`:

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "registry.terraform.io/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
  version = "~> 3.14.0"

  for_each = var.enabled ? toset(["this"]) : []

  name = var.environment
  cidr = var.vpc_cidr
  azs             = var.az
  private_subnets = var.private_subnets
  private_subnet_tags = var.private_subnet_tags
  public_subnets  = var.public_subnets
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support = true
  enable_nat_gateway = true
  single_nat_gateway = true
  one_nat_gateway_per_az = false
}
```

Comment: v0.13 also added support for [count](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/count) here, so slightly more clear would be `count = var.enabled ? 1 : 0`.

Comment: I didn't understand the toset(["this"]) part. What did u mean by "this".

Comment: It doesn't really mean anything other than "something". It could also be `toset([1])` or `toset(["bacon"])`. But it should work with `count` as in your question.

Comment: @winter Hashicorp advocates naming resources `this` when no proper name exists. I have extended this to optional modules and optional resources. Note that optional dynamic blocks have no keys associated with them, and therefore do not need a key name. It just needs to be type `set(string)`.

Answer (score 0):

This might not have existed when the original question was asked but you can achieve what you're looking for by using a `moved` block to instruct Terraform that your previously created resource now has a new name but doesn't need to be recreated it.

In your case

```terraform
moved {
  from = module.vpc
  to   = module.vpc[0]
}
```

Next time you `terraform plan`, Terraform will print a line that looks like this for every resource defined in `vpc` and won't try to destroy/recreate anymore.

> module.vpc.some_resource has moved to module.vpc[0].some_resource

See https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/refactoring#enabling-count-or-for_each-for-a-module-call